# What is the correct way to reset and load new data into GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Tags: opengl, c++, color

I am using an array buffer for colors data. If I want to load different colors for the current mesh in real time what is the correct way to do it. At the moment I am doing:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SIZE, colorsData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader->attrib("color"));
glVertexAttribPointer(shader->attrib("color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, NULL);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

It works, but I am not sure if this is good and efficient way to do it. What happens to the previous data ? Does it write on top of it ?

Do I need to call :

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, colorBuffer);
glGenBuffers(1, colorBuffer);
```

before transfering the new data into the buffer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glBufferData()` overwrites the previous data, and is generally what you should use to load new data into a GL buffer. Conceptually it is similar to overwriting data in an array.

`glDeleteBuffers()` and `glGenBuffers()` destroy and recreate a buffer. Conceptually they are similar to `free()` and `malloc()`. If you're just writing new data into the buffer, destroying it and recreating it is not only overkill, but will almost certainly bring a performance penalty.

But, above all, what is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rebind the VAO or reset the vertex attributes. You can just overwrite the data in place:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SIZE, colorsData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

When glDraw* is called the new data will be used.

I use `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` because you would change the data often whereas `GL_STATIC_DRAW` would indicate that you won't change it often. It really doesn't make a difference but allows the driver to optimize differently.